# Transfer time with socket

Tags: linux, image, sockets, tcp, throughput

Actually, I am working on a embedded system, and I send image through socket. I use linux for both sides (client and server).

The throughput of the Ethernet is 1000Mbit/s. I try to figure out the time to send one image. It is 32-bit image (float), with that dimension : **6004*7920** .
I expect that transfer time :

**(6004*7920*4*8)/(1000000000) = 1.52 s**

From my code, this time is **2.1 s**. I do not understand that difference. Does the time for the protocol .. ?

Notice that I have already increased the jumbo frame to 9000.
Thank for you for your help !

Comment: Kindly share your code if you'd like assistance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to keep in mind about that 1000Mb/sec transfer-rate figure is that it is the theoretical maximum, not the speed you are going to often actually obtain in practice.  The measured rate is likely to be [somewhat lower](https://www.gigabit-wireless.com/gigabit-wireless/actual-maximum-throughput-gigabit-ethernet/).

Some reasons why the measured rate is likely to be lower than the theoretical rate are (in no particular order):

1. Overhead due to TCP packet headers and Ethernet frame headers
2. Dropped packets (which cause the TCP stream to halt briefly so that the dropped packet(s) can be resent)
3. CPU or memory-bandwidth limitations on the sending or receiving hardware
4. TCP's [slow-start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control#Slow_start) feature that reduces the transmission rate at the beginning of the session
5. Other network traffic competing for the same bandwidth
6. Sub-optimal implementations of the sending or receiving code (e.g. maybe the receiving program spends time writing received data to disk, delaying its next call to `recv()`, allowing its TCP-receive-buffer to overflow)
7. Reduced transmission speed due to marginal Ethernet-cable quality or excessive cable-length

As a side note, if you want to decrease the time it takes to transmit your image, you might look into compressing the data before sending it (e.g. by converting to a .jpg on the sending side).  If you can significantly reduce the amount of data you are sending, you can correspondingly reduce the transmission time.  (you might further speed things up by doing the compression in a separate thread on the server side, so that compression of image #(N+1) can happen in parallel with the transmission of image #N)

Comment: Hi,

Many thanks for you comprehensive answer, it is more clear now !
Actually, I worked using ssh through ethernet. Closing the ssh session reduce the transfer time of 200 ms. I am going to try with better ethernet cable.
Compress the image is a good idea but I  can't do it, I have to minimize the noise.

Thank you again !

Comment: Lossless compression (eg with ZLib) might be worth trying.